# include and filter collection on EF lambda

Tags: entity-framework, lambda

lest say i have an entity "A" that has a collection of "B", also, B has a collections of "B_1",B_2",B_3" like:

```
A---->B
      |---->B_1
      |---->B_2
      |---->B_3
```

what is the best way to include all of them and filter them when "B" has a field like is_active set to false?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Any` to filter them:

```
var data = from a in context.As
           where a.Bs.Any(b => b.IsActive == true)
           select a;
```